# how to send OTP to email for email verification in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, one-time-password

The firebase has an email verification feature. but the firebase is sending verification links to email, not Verification OTP. can anyone please help me to send OTP to email for email verification from my own email?

Answer (score 0):

you can send email verification using firebase  and you can also use packages to send otp to emails
[here is 1 ways to send using firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLGe44gaEUM&t=15s)

[packages to send OTP to email](https://pub.dev/packages/email_auth)

Comment: I used Email_auth package, but i am facing this problem.

Comment: I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> Remote server is not available -- using test server --
I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> ❗ Warning this is not reliable on production
I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> OTP sent successfully ✅
I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> The remote server configurations are valid

Comment: the Email_auth package is initializing the remote server soo late. so when I send OTP for the first time it is sending the OTP from the test server, and then for the second time, it is sending email from remote server.

Comment: can you please help me with this problem

Comment: https://saran-surya.github.io/email-auth-node/

Comment: It's not possible to change the link to OTP, by that I mean you can't change the body of an email sent by firebase to verify email due to spam issues.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. But you can create your own logic using firestore or realtime database. When user sign up, create a document with "user_id", random 6 "digitOTP" and "emailVerified" property.

The `emailVerified` property will be `false` initially and right after that send the same `OTP` to his `email` which he provided during signup..

There are packages out there which can be used to send emails and customize them or you can use `firebase functions and node mailer` in it.

Anyway, make a screen where user input the OTP copied from email and check it against `'digitOTP'` property in firestore, if it matches then set the `'emailVerified' from false to true`...

And when user login check if the 'emailVerified' is true or false, if false send again the OTP and repeat the process until it's true...